# How to sort the average mark with elements in a text file in Java

Tags: arrays, sorting, text

There is a text file which include student names, scores.
I got the average marks of each student by using a Constructor.
But, I have no idea how to sort the average marks with elements in the text file.

- John 95 75 88
- Alice 88 95 75
- Johnson 95 75 88
- Dennis 60 100 100
- Jack 77 84 93
- Tod 84 86 80
- Tom 68 70 75
- Dave 90 90 92
- David 99 70 87
- Trent 89 77 90
- Bob 100 67 89
- Fiona 77 89 90
- Peter 80 88 82
- Amy 85 95 78
- Nancy 83 93 82
- Richard 81 91 86
- Daniel 77 78 79
- James 80 90 85
- Cathy 95 74 89
- Paul 84 87 79

These are the element in the text file.

- Expected output like:
- Student Average  Physic  Chemistry  Maths
- John      90       88       90        92
- Trent     88       87       88        89

```
    public class Student {
        String name;
        int physic;
        int chemistry;
        int math;
        int ave;

        public Student(String name, int physic, int chemistry, int math) {
            this.name = name;
            this.physic = physic;
            this.chemistry = chemistry;
            this.math = math;

            int sum = this.physic + this.chemistry + this.math;
            this.ave = sum / 3;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setPhysic(int physic) {
                this.physic = physic;
        }
        public void setChemistry(int chemistry) {
            this.chemistry = chemistry;
        }
        public void setMath(int math) {
            this.math = math;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public int getPhysic() {
            return this.physic;
        }
        public int getChemistry() {
            return this.chemistry;
        }
        public int getMath() {
            return this.math;
        }

        public int getAve() {
            return this.ave;
        }

    }
```

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Comparator;

    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Student[] student = readData("students.txt");
            sortStudents(student);
            display();

        }
    private static Student[] readData(String filename) {
            int nStudent = 0;
            Student[] student = new Student[20];
            //filename = "students.txt";
            String string = null;

            try {
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                while((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] arr = string.split(" ");
                        student[nStudent] = new Student(arr[0], Integer.parseInt(arr[1]), Integer.parseInt(arr[2]), Integer.parseInt(arr[3]));

                    nStudent++;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return student;
        }

        private static void display() {
            Student[] students = readData("students.txt");
            sortStudents(students);
            System.out.println("Student     AverageScore      Physic        Chemistry         Maths");
            for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(students[i].getName() + "\t\t" + students[i].getAve() + "\t\t" + students[i].getPhysic() + "\t\t" + students[i].getChemistry() + "\t\t" + students[i].getMath());
            }
        }
    public static Student[] sortStudents(Student[] student) {
        //I need to sort the average marks of each student in the descending order.
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to calculate the averages? The mapping of John's grades from "95 75 88" to "90 88 90 92" isn't clear to me.

Comment: I need to calculate the average of each student's total grades. then, sort the average

Comment: So what you are trying to do is to calculate the average as an integer, insert it into the list/array of grades, and then sort that entire list of grades+average, correct?

Comment: yes that is what I am tring to do.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your smaller methods.

main():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    display();
}
```

display():

```
private static void display() {
    Student[] students = readData("students.txt");
    System.out.println("Student     AverageScore      Physic        Chemistry         Maths");
    for (Student student : students) {
        int[] sortedGrades = sortStudentGrades(student);
        System.out.println(student.getName() + "\t\t" + sortedGrades[0] + "\t\t" + sortedGrades[1] + "\t\t" + sortedGrades[2] + "\t\t" + sortedGrades[3]);
    }
}
```

The last thing that I changed was to change the `sortStudents()` method to the `sortStudentGrades()` method. Sorting students doesn't really do much good, and you there's no field to store the grades in the current `Student` object. As such, you need something that can sort an array of grades with the average without changing the `Student` object.

sortStudents() -> sortStudentGrades():

```
public static int[] sortStudentGrades(Student student) {
    int[] grades = new int[] {student.getAve(), student.getChemistry(), student.getPhysic(), student.getMath()};
    Arrays.sort(grades);
    return grades;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

First take care about double cast. But you can implement the Comparable class like this

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
private String name;
int physic;
int chemistry;
int math;
double ave;

public Student(String name, int physic, int chemistry, int math) {
    this.name = name;
    this.physic = physic;
    this.chemistry = chemistry;
    this.math = math;

    int sum = this.physic + this.chemistry + this.math;
    this.ave = (double)sum / 3;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return Double.compare(o.ave, ave);//for descending order
}    
}
```

and in your main you can use Arrays.sort(Student_tab);
e.g:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student a = new Student("john", 40, 23, 44);
    System.out.println("a = "+ a.ave);
    Student b = new Student("john", 50, 23, 44);
    System.out.println("b = "+ b.ave);

    Student[] tab = {a,b};
    Arrays.sort(tab);
    System.out.println(" 1: "+ tab[0].ave);
    System.out.println(" 2: "+ tab[1].ave);
}
```

Indeed the array of students is ordered we get the following result:

//Disorder:

a = 35.666666666666664
b = 39.0

//Ordered:

1: 39.0
 2: 35.666666666666664